# How to manifest billing permission in adobe air?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I know that I have to add billing permission but how can I do it manually as I don't see billing permission in default permissions of **Air for Android** settings > permissions.

```
 <android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                ...
                <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>

            </manifest>
        ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the checkbox "Manually manage permissions and manifest..." and click OK, then you will see a .xml file appear right beside your .fla file, open it with any text editor and copy-paste manifest permissions you have into that file, you will see *android* and *manifestAdditions* tags, just replace them with one you have, save and recompile your fla, done!

**Edit: App-xml sample.**
Please consider that there may be some activities provided by your ane extension developer, too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/30.0">
    <id>Main</id>
    <filename>Main</filename>
    <name>Main</name>
    <versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>

    <initialWindow>
        <content>SWF file name is set automatically at compile time</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    </initialWindow>

    <android>
        <manifestAdditions>
            <![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

                <!-- required for billing extension -->
                <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

                <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:allowBackup="true">

                </application>
            </manifest>
            ]]>
        </manifestAdditions>
    </android>

</application>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering and sorry for delayed response but when i recompile the fla , the manifest tags go away.

Comment: Are you using an IDE to compile, like Flash Builder, IntelliJ or …? If so, probably your IDE is using a self generated app-xml file.

Comment: But if you are using Flash/Animate itself, make sure  "Manually manage permissions..." checkbox is selected and that window is closed while you are saving changes you've made to xml file.

Comment: Using Animated CC, I believe I did everything correctly saving setting , adding permission to XML, is there any Adobe example where I can look up ?

Comment: I edit this post and add a sample xml to it, but you may consider that anyone providing billing .ane extension would provide this sample for you.